# Using d3j to select an element in an embedded SVG file

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
<body>
    <button type="button" id="changeButton" onClick="hide(this)">Hide</button><br>
    <br>
    <object data="graphdata.svg" id="myGraph">graph</object>

<script src="d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    state="visible";
    function hide(button) {


        console.log(d3.select("body").select("#myGraph").select("svg")); // ??
        if (state=="visible") { value="none"; state="invisible"; }
        else { value=""; state="visible"; }

        button.firstChild.data = state=="visible" ? "Hide" : "Unhide";
    }
</script>
</body>
```

The SVG in question is [here](https://gist.github.com/Skyyrunner/cc6c7c70adc388c9dceb#file-graphdata-svg).

The basic structure is

```
<svg>
    <g id="edges"></g>
    ....
    <g id="node-labels">
        <text class="thing1"></text>
        <text class="thing2"></text>
        ....
        </g>
</svg>
```

I am trying to select the  SVG element so I can set the attribute "display" to be "none", but every attempt I make returns a null element from `.select()`.

Comment: Assuming you do not want to simply place the `svg` in your page which could make things simple, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54dnt/), it looks like your object tag needs some refining...see [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/svg/qt/add-svg-to-html.htm).

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes: I suppose I could go that way, too, since I'm planning on serving the pages dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM selectors that D3 uses are, as their name suggests, confined to the particular DOM that you're in. By embedding an SVG like this, you end up with a new, separate DOM for it. The selector will not traverse DOM boundaries, but you can select the root element of the new DOM, change into it and run your selector there. The code would look something like this.

```
d3.select(document.getElementById("#myGraph").documentElement).select("svg");
```